# Как грамотно составить структуру показа важной информации

Tags: java, база-данных, json

Есть приложение, распространятся оно будет через подписку. На данный момент эта информация находится в базе данных, так вот суть в чем, как грамотно реализовать отправку информации от базы к клиенту? Я так понимаю, не желательно делать так, чтобы приложение на прямую обращалась к базе данных? Очень важна скорость передачи, какие советы можете дать? Я еще новичек в Java, и думаю может сделать сервер, который будет принимать запрос от приложения, вытягивать всю инфу с бд и передавать ее в виде json, или оно того не стоит?

Comment: Здесь важно насколько частые нужны апдейты, какой примерно объём данных будет в апдейтах, насколько важно передавать обновления быстро. Что является клиентом -- браузер, приложение в телефоне?

Comment: @nzeemin Объем ~300 рядов(или как их назвать, в голову не приходит) в бд, передавать информацию нужно каждую секунду +-, скорость передачи самая приоритетная в этой задаче. Десктоп приложение на JavaFX

Comment: ~300 индивидуально каждому или всем клиентам одно и тоже? Что за структура данных?

Comment: @EvgeniyG всем клиентам одно и тоже. Не совсем понял второй вопрос, но попытаюсь на него ответить - инфа находится в базе данных mysql

Comment: Данные лежат в базе статически (редко меняются) или поступаю из внешнего источника. Если поступают из внешнего источника то с какой скорость?

Comment: @Евгений меняются каждую секунду

Comment: И сколько одновременно будет клиентов? Вы всё про базу говорите, а между тем узким местом выглядит передача данных. 300 записей каждую секунду каждому клиенту -- это интенсивность трейдерской системы по сути.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал, для начала, сделать rest api веб сервис и отправлять данные в json. В сервисе вы должны реализовать авторизацию клиента. Для вашей задачи протокола http будет достаточно. Преимущества такого решения простота реализации и отвязка от языка программирования. В дальнейшем можно нарастить функциональность в виде кэширования и прочего. Так как в этом случае вы определяете только протокол получения данных, а сама реализация клиента и сервера может быть на любом языке.

Алгоритм простой. Клиент каждую секунду обращается к сервису за новой порцией данных, в параметрах запроса указывая строку с которой нужно получить новые данные (такой себе аналог RSS). Сервис после получения запроса идёт в бд и смотрит появились ли новые (в контексте клиента) строки в бд и если да, то возвращает их.

Всё что я описал выше можно реализовать для начала, но потом с увеличением нагрузки нужно будет смотреть оставить запрос данных клиентом или смотреть в сторону websocket и толкать новые данные с сервера на клиент.

p.s. Светить базу данных наружу настоятельно не рекомендую.

Answer (score 0):

У вас узким местом явно будет рассылка данных на клиентов.
Советую сразу смотреть в сторону WebSocket в качестве канала передачи данных.
Кроме того, такая интенсивность передачи потребует постоянно держать соединение открытым -- вопрос сколько будет клиентов одновременно.

Для сериализации тоже нужно что-то эффективное -- посмотрите на protobuf. В нём команда занимает 1 байт. Команда с параметром -- 1 байт + размер параметра. Соответственно, размеры пакетов будут мелкими, передаваться быстро.

Вы всё время думаете о базе данных, между тем здесь это наименее критичная вещь. Для интенсивной отправки данных клиентам, данные вы всё равно будете держать в памяти.